# Casting a hex number under unchecked scope

Tags: c#, binary, hex

Well I am trying to understand how negative numbers work and trying to cast a hex number as we can see below to a singed integer, but the question is **why does this work only under "unchecked" scope?**

```
 unchecked
 {
     signedInt = (int)0xffffffff; // -1 (1111........ 1111)
     signedInt = (int)0xfffffffd; // -3 (1111........ 1101)

 }
```

Comment: Linked duplicate contains explanation of the behavior by the Eric Lippert. If you want more similar questions - search for error message https://www.bing.com/search?q=Constant+value+%274294967295%27+cannot+be+converted+to+a+%27int%27+(use+%27unchecked%27+syntax+to+override)

Comment: Ok thank you , if necessary I will close the topic.